# GODUS crashes on startup after I've already played for a long time. Is there a way to fix this?

Tags: technical-issues, godus

I've been playing GODUS for about 19 hours now, and nothing has been going wrong. Recently, when I went to start it up again, the game **crashed** before the cursor managed to appear or anything even loaded. This now happens every time I try to start it, and I can't play!

Is there any way to fix this - **without losing my save data**, preferrably?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with **your save file**. Thankfully, GODUS frequently backs it up, so you can fix the game without even having to reinstall.

In your GODUS save files directory (`SteamApps/common/Godus/prf[a whole bunch of numbers]/`), there are a whole bunch of files, depending on how much you have played. The error is in **`state.bin`**. Simply **remove `state.bin`** and GODUS will load `state.back` instead, letting you launch the game as normal without losing any progress.